# I actually want Submitted date and Approved date for every step in the Approval Process

Tags: apex, approval-process, approval-history

I am getting the Submitted Date from ProcessInstanceStep.CreatedDate but not being able to get the approved date for each step. CompletedDate date is giving the date for overall completion of the Approval process but not for every step.Can anyone provide me with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The "Date" on the "Approval History" related list contains the date and time that a request was approved. If there are multiple approval steps, each of them will show up with its own date and time once it is approved.

[image]

Comment: Can we query ApprovalHistory?

Comment: I solved it using the ProcessInstanceNode object. It gives the Completed Date for each step unlike ProcessInstanceStep.